# Using image built by kaniko in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker, kaniko

How can I use an image built by kaniko in Jenkins pipeline? I want to build the image, use that image to run tests for my app, and then push the image. With docker that would look something like this:

```
steps {
  container('docker') {
    script {
      myimage = docker.build('image:tag')
    }
  }
  container('docker') {
    script {
      myimage.inside {
        sh 'pipenv run test'
      }
    }
  }
  # and somewhere below I would use `docker.withRegistry('some registry') { myimage.push() }
}
```

I am not sure how to translate that part `myimage.inside` from docker. With kaniko I have this:

```
steps {
  container('kaniko') {
    script {
      sh '/kaniko/executor --tar-path=myimage.tar --context . --no-push --destination myregistry:tag'
    }
  }
  container(???) {
    # how can I use that image from above to run my tests??
  }
  # and somewhere below I use `crane` to push the image.
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but whole pipeline would run in kubernetes environment, thus I would want to avoid using docker in docker (DinD).